# Validity control and password comparison in a form in Java

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to add validity control in a form like

- no empty fields are allowed
- email address has to be in the format name@domain
- date has to be in the format dd.mm.yyyy
- to compare passwords

Also, after these checks I couldn't figure out how to stop further processing of the form, and make the user enter the missing or wrong data again, before the submission of the form is accepted.

Here is my code:

```
package examsuite;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class SignUp extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
JLabel jlb,jlfna,jllna,jldob,jlqu,jlph,jlpw,jlpc,jlem;
JTextField jtfna,jtlna,jtdob,jtqu,jtph,jtem;
JPasswordField jtpw, jtpc;
JButton jbsav,jblog;
Container c;
Connection conn;
PreparedStatement pstmt;

SignUp()
{
try
{
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:ExamSuite","","");
}
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
{
        System.out.println("class not exception");
}
    catch(SQLException e)
{
        System.out.println("sql exception");
}     

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public void setUp()
{
        c=getContentPane();
        setSize(900,750);
        setTitle("Exam Suite");
        c.setBackground(Color.white);
        c.setLayout(null);

        jlb=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("uit.jpg"));
        jlb.setBounds(0,0,900,120);

        jlfna=new JLabel("First Name");
        jlfna.setBounds(260,170,120,30);

        jtfna=new JTextField();
        jtfna.setBounds(440,170,120,30);

        jllna=new JLabel("Last Name");
        jllna.setBounds(260,230,120,30);

        jtlna=new JTextField();
        jtlna.setBounds(440,230,120,30);

        jldob=new JLabel("Date of Birth");
        jldob.setBounds(260,290,120,30);

        jtdob=new JTextField();
        jtdob.setBounds(440,290,120,30);

        jlqu=new JLabel("Qualification");
        jlqu.setBounds(260,350,120,30);

        jtqu=new JTextField();
        jtqu.setBounds(440,350,120,30);

        jlph=new JLabel("Phone No.");
        jlph.setBounds(260,410,120,30);

        jtph=new JTextField();
        jtph.setBounds(440,410,120,30);

        jlem=new JLabel("E mail");
        jlem.setBounds(260,470,120,30);

        jtem=new JTextField();
        jtem.setBounds(440,470,120,30);

        jlpw=new JLabel("Password");
        jlpw.setBounds(260,530,120,30);

        jtpw=new JPasswordField();
        jtpw.setBounds(440,530,120,30);

        jlpc=new JLabel("Confirm Password");
        jlpc.setBounds(260,590,120,30);

        jtpc=new JPasswordField();
        jtpc.setBounds(440,590,120,30);

        jbsav=new JButton("Save");  
        jbsav.setBounds(260,650,100,30);

        jblog=new JButton("Go to Login");   
        jblog.setBounds(460,650,100,30);

        c.add(jlb);
        c.add(jlfna);
        c.add(jtfna);
        c.add(jllna);
        c.add(jtlna);   
        c.add(jldob);
        c.add(jtdob);
        c.add(jlqu);
        c.add(jtqu);
        c.add(jlph);
        c.add(jtph);
        c.add(jlem);
        c.add(jtem);
        c.add(jlpw);
        c.add(jtpw);
        c.add(jlpc);
        c.add(jtpc);

        c.add(jbsav);
        c.add(jblog);

        jbsav.addActionListener(this);
        jblog.addActionListener(this);

        setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    String s=ae.getActionCommand();
    Object obj=ae.getSource();
    String email=new String(" ");
    if(s.equals("Save"))
    {

                if(jtfna.getText().equals("") | jtlna.getText().equals("") | jtdob.getText().equals("")
                   | jtqu.getText().equals("") | jtph.getText().equals("") | jtem.getText().equals("")
                   | jtpw.getText().equals("") | jtpc.getText().equals(""))
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error entering data - All fields must be filled.", "Exam Suite - Data Entry Error", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                }
                else if(!(jtpw.getText().equals(jtpc)))
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error entering password - Passwords do not match.", "Exam Suite - Password Entry Error", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                }

        try
        {
            pstmt=conn.prepareStatement("insert into registration values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

            String fname=jtfna.getText();
            pstmt.setString(2,fname);
            String lname=jtlna.getText();
            pstmt.setString(3,lname);
            String dob=jtdob.getText();
            pstmt.setString(4,dob);
            String qual=jtqu.getText();
            pstmt.setString(5,qual);
            String ph=jtph.getText();
            pstmt.setString(6,ph);
            email=jtem.getText();
            pstmt.setString(1,email);
            String pw=jtpw.getText();
            pstmt.setString(7,pw);

            pstmt.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch(SQLException se)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (this, "Error in saving the file", "Exam Suite - SQL Error", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (this, "Successful Registration ", "Exam Suite ", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        jtfna.setText("");
        jtlna.setText("");
        jtdob.setText("");
        jtqu.setText("");
        jtph.setText("");
        jtem.setText("");
        jtpw.setText(""); 
    }

    if(s.equals("Go to Login"))
    {
        new LogFom().setup();
        setVisible(false);
    }       
}   

//public static void main(String args[])
//{
//  SignUp rt=new SignUp();
//  rt.setUp();
//}
```

}

Comment: that's not how you store a password a DB because you do **NOT** store a password in a DB.  You typically save a cryptographic hash of the password (with a salt preferably) and you then hash what the user entered and compare that hash to the hash from your DB.

Comment: unrelated but important: dont null the LayoutManager! Instead learn how each (of those provided in core and widely used 3rd party managers like MigLayout, FormLayout, DesignGridLayout) are working and choose one that fits your needs

Answer (score 0):

> Also, after these checks I couldn't figure out how to stop further
>   processing of the form ...

```
if(jtfna.getText().equals("") | jtlna.getText().equals("") | jtdob.getText().equals("")
                   | jtqu.getText().equals("") | jtph.getText().equals("") | jtem.getText().equals("")
                   | jtpw.getText().equals("") | jtpc.getText().equals(""))
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error entering data - All fields must be filled.", "Exam Suite - Data Entry Error", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                    //RETURN WITHOUT GOING AHEAD 
                    return;
                }
                else if(!(jtpw.getText().equals(jtpc)))
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error entering password - Passwords do not match.", "Exam Suite - Password Entry Error", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                  //RETURN WITHOUT GOING AHEAD 
                  return;
                }
```

However it is better iterate through each component of the user interface with a for loop and when you find a component that must be filled show an optionpane with also the name of the control that the user must fill, or better change the background color(red for example) of the component that must be filled by the user ...

Comment: Great idea about the for loop! Thank you for helping. Now I only don't know how to solve this: 
- email address has to be in the format name@domain
- date has to be in the format dd.mm.yyyy

Comment: You can do that using a regular expression validation for example.